# How to set date clause for prevous month in sql?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to get last values for prevous month (universal, not just for january :))

How can I set up where condition? Now it works well for current month, but i want result for prevous.

```
SELECT     MAX(v.timestamp) AS Date, 
           MAX(v.value) AS Stanje,
           v.tag_id, t.prik_sifr, t.tag_name
FROM       dbo.tag_values AS v INNER JOIN
           dbo.typ_tag AS t ON v.tag_id = t.id
    WHERE       (t.prik_sifr IS NOT NULL) AND (t.unit = 'M3') AND 
        (DATEPART(YEAR, v.timestamp) = DATEPART(YEAR, SYSDATETIME())) AND 
        (DATEPART(MONTH, v.timestamp)= DATEPART(MONTH, SYSDATETIME()))    GROUP BY v.tag_id, t.prik_sifr, t.tag_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtruct one month from the current date:

```
SELECT     MAX(v.timestamp) AS Date, 
           MAX(v.value) AS Stanje,
           v.tag_id, t.prik_sifr, t.tag_name
FROM       dbo.tag_values AS v INNER JOIN
           dbo.typ_tag AS t ON v.tag_id = t.id
    WHERE       (t.prik_sifr IS NOT NULL) AND (t.unit = 'M3') AND 
        (DATEPART(YEAR, v.timestamp) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1 SYSDATETIME()))) AND 
        (DATEPART(MONTH, v.timestamp)= DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1 SYSDATETIME())))
GROUP BY v.tag_id, t.prik_sifr, t.tag_name)
```